# Copy files in different gulp tasks to same folder

Tags: stream, copy, gulp

I have files in folders like this:

```
- source_a
--- file_x
--- file_y
--- file_z
- source_b
--- file_z
- dest
```

And i want to copy all files from `source_a` to `dest`, after this finish i want to copy all files from `source_b` to `dest` so that `file_z` will be runover.

Here is my code

```
gulp.task("myCopy", ["copy_a"], function() {
    return gulp.src('source_b').pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
});

gulp.task("copy_a", [], function(theme) {
return [
        gulp.src('source_b').pipe(gulp.dest('dest')),
        gulp.src('other_stuff').pipe(gulp.dest('to_other_places'))
    ];
});
```

But eventually all the files in `dest` are from `source_a`... if i run again `copy_a` in separate run it works... what am i missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Eventually i used fs-extra to syncCopy...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create 2 copy tasks and run them in sequence, like so:

```
gulp.task('copy_a', function(){
  // copy all from folder A 
  return gulp.src('source_a/**').pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
});

gulp.task('copy_b', function(){
  // copy all from folder B
  return gulp.src('source_b/**').pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
});

gulp.task('copy', function(cb) {
  var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

  runSequence('copy_a', 'copy_b', cb); // run in sequence
});
```

This way your `copy` task run in sequence, task `copy_b` only starts when `copy_a` has finished.

Just call the `copy` task and you'll be on your way.

Comment: my bad.. gave runSequence an array, resulting in a parallel run... runSequence('copy_a', 'copy_b', cb); will do the trick. Changed my answer.

Comment: Elger, it's still not working, and i can't see the reason why it should work. runSequence will do the same thing as i did. When i set tasks dependency between both of my tasks i know that they will run async, no need ro add runSequence. It's something about the stream, the dependency is ok.

Comment: Please read https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support: by returning a stream, tasks are made async. The use of run-sequence gives you the possibility to run in sequence. When I run my task (mentioned above), then the `copy_b` will only fire when `copy_a` is finised. Please read docs from https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence

Comment: That is true (and also when i use tasks dependencies). Still, the issue is not solved. It will not help to argue about something we both agree.